# How to select date datatype from database in JSP page using Struts 2

Tags: java

JSP page:

```
<s:date name="arrdate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<s:date name="depdate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<s:property value="roomno"/>
<s:property value="states"/>
```

Java:

```
bean = new ResverstionBean();

bean.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
bean.setArrdate(rs.getDate("arrdate"));
System.out.println(bean.arrdate);
bean.setDepdate(rs.getDate("depdate"));
System.out.println(bean.depdate);
bean.setRoomno(rs.getInt("roomno"));
bean.setStates(rs.getBoolean("states"));
System.out.println(bean.id);

System.out.println(bean.states);

userBeans.add(bean);
```

I got the data from database:

> 2018-05-23
>   2018-05-25
>   7
>   true

But the data does not show in the JSP page please help me.

Comment: <s:date name="arrdate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />

Comment: <s:date name="depdate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />  <s:property value="roomno"/>  <s:property value="states"/> this is the jsp page code